# How to install pylsmlib python module on Linux

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to install the module pylsmlib for python to use it on fipy.

I was following instructions from [here](https://github.com/ktchu/LSMLIB/tree/master/pylsmlib#pylsmlib). I was able to install LSMLIB python module using the method outlined.

```
$ cd .../LSMLIB
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ ../configure
$ make
$ make install
```

The problem comes when I want to finish the second part of the code that is

```
$ cd .../LSMLIB/pylsmlib
$ python setup.py install
```

it raises the error

```
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.14.tar.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 12, in <module>
    ez_setup.use_setuptools()
  File "/home/alpha/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ez_setup.py", line 145, in use_setuptools
    return _do_download(version, download_base, to_dir, download_delay)
  File "/home/alpha/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ez_setup.py", line 124, in _do_download
    to_dir, download_delay)
  File "/home/alpha/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ez_setup.py", line 193, in download_setuptools
    src = urlopen(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 435, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 548, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 473, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 556, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: SSL is required
```

Am using Debian 10 OS. I would like to know how to go around this error.

Comment: Please include the full error traceback as text using appropriate formatting. Also please indicate your OS and python version (looks like you are using python 2.7).

Comment: @FlyingTeller am using python 2.7 and Debian 10. I have also added the full error

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are not using the recommended and supported version of the language, which is Python 3?

Comment: @tripleee I want using python 2.7 because I plan to use Fipy which runs well on 2.7 than 3.

Comment: Your OS distributed `pip` version is probably outdated 
(check with `pip --version)`. Try upgrading it to a newer version

Comment: @FlyingTeller I did upgrade pip just now after seeing your comment. I run $ python2 -m pip install --upgrade pip and it upgraded to pip 19.2.2 . But the error is still the same

Answer (score 0):

Back in October 2017 Distutils have disabled http access: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2017-October/031714.html

Your options are:

1) Get updated setup.py

2) Modify setup.py from "http" to "https" in lines where it is used, such as

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 548, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
```

But to be honest that will lead you down the rabbit hole...

Best to upgrade your tools to latest versions.

Hope this helps.